# Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-expect' [Protractor]

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor, git-bash

Im trying to run a protractor test that simply connects to my application.

When I run (git bash/terminal):

```
   protractor conf.js
```

I receive the following error: "

> Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-expect'

After seeing this, I went ahead and installed the module:

```
npm install -g jasmine-expect
```

But I still receive the same failure.

Here is my test:

```
describe('DragAndDrop Test', function () {
require('protractor');
require('jasmine-expect');


beforeAll(function () {
    context = new Context();
    context.get();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
});

it('should drag and drop Application Experience tile', function () {

    //target is where we are dragging the box to.  Box is the Box
    var target = { x: 300, y: 50 };
    var box = element(by.cssContainingText('h3', 'Application Experience'));

    //scope is going to hold the scope variables that tell us where the box is located
    //get the standardItems Scope

    box.evaluate('dashboards').then(function(scope) {
        //make sure the box we are using is initially set in column 0 and Row 0
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].col).toEqual(0);
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].row).toEqual(0);
    });

    //drag and drop the box somewhere else.
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(box, target).perform();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);

    //get the updated scope
    box.evaluate('dashboards').then(function(scope) {
        //test to see that the box was actually moved to column 1 and row 0
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].col).toEqual(1);
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].row).toEqual(0);
    });
});

});

var Context = function () {
this.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //load the website
    this.get = function () {
        browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:62734/index.html#/dashboard');
    };
};
```

Here is my conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['gridster-Test.js'],
    capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'
   }
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try installing the package without using the `-g` flag:

```
npm install jasmine-expect
```

Also, move the `require('jasmine-expect');` from under the `describe` into the `onPrepare()` in your Protractor configuration file:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    require("jasmine-expect");
},
```

Comment: tried installing without the -g flag in addition to the onPrepare() you suggested. Same error message. It cannot find the jasmine-expect. It installed successfully so i don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the dependency is being added to your package.json file.

```
npm install jasmine-expect --save-dev
```